# iptables - Port Forwarding from Multiple Sources

Tags: networking, iptables

(Originally asked on StackOverflow. Thanks **Ken White** for redirecting me here.)

Ubuntu 16.04 amd64 with 3 NICs

NIC1: External IP `$WAN_IP`
NIC2: Internal LAN `$LAN_IP`
NIC3: Infrastructure LAN `$INF_IP`
(the infrastructure LAN is where all the servers reside, purposely away from Desktops and Personal Computers)

I want to port forward requests from NIC1 and NIC2 to a specific server on NIC3. I am able to do this, and everything works properly. My problem is, I am unable to reliably set the `--to-source` field in iptables.

This is what I have so far:

```
iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -p udp -d $WAN_IP --dport 1194 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.26.105 # VPN Server on the $INF_IP subnet
iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -p udp -d $LAN_IP --dport 1194 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.26.105
iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -p udp -d $INF_IP --dport 1194 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.26.105
# The above code routes port 1194:udp (openvpn) to the VPN Server 26.105 properly
# The -j SNAT below is where I encounter problems
iptables -A POSTROUTING -t nat -p udp -m udp -s 192.168.26.105 --dport 1194 -j SNAT --to-source ????
```

The above **????** in the `POSTROUTING -j SNAT` is where I run into the problem. I have 3 potential IPs I can set this to, and no reliable way to set it. If I set it to `$WAN_IP`, anything on `$LAN_IP` and `$INF_IP` will received the incorrect source packets.

How can I use iptables (or alternative) to properly set the `SOURCE` address regardless of which interface the request comes from.

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Not sure why the sent you here nothing specific about notables and Ubuntu. At any rate can you try `iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE`

Comment: If that rule does not work see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/209031/nat-box-with-multiple-internal-and-external-interfaces you will have to adapt the routing table and nat rules